# 3D image processing with volume images in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am looking forward for tutorials for 3d image processing in Opencv. I have the the O'Reilly publication book , which is a nice one for 2D image processing in Opencv. Can any one please introduce me some sources for 3D image processing ?

Comment: OpenCV is generally for 2D rather than 3D.

Comment: And I would suggest ITK librabry for 3D processing: http://www.itk.org/

Comment: also opencv 3.0 has vtk (itk.org) support http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/viz/table_of_content_viz/table_of_content_viz.html, as well as PCL library http://pointclouds.org/

Comment: when you say 3d image processing, do you mean something like kinect data? where for each pixel you have a distance?

Comment: No more like volume rendering

Answer (score 5):

3D image in this question stands for volume data, typically means 2D images series like CT/MRI data. There are several libraries useful below:

[VTK](https://www.vtk.org/): Visualization Toolkit, is originally designed for visualize 3D volume data, some core algorithms like [ray casting](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VolumeRendering/SmartVolumeMapper) and [marching cubes](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Modelling/MarchingCubes) are provided.

[ITK](https://itk.org/): Insight toolkit, brother of VTK, they are developed both by Kitware. ITK is for 3d image processing like registration and segmentation, it has no visualization methods, so you will have to use VTK to visualize the result.

[PCL](http://pointclouds.org/): Point clouds library, sometimes researchers convert 3d images to point cloud and do some further processing based on them, this way PCL would be useful.

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/): The most commonly used image processing and vision library. As comments above indicated, it is not designed for 3D images (volume data) especially, but many many 3D image problems are solved from 2D ways, e.g. segmentation of 3D CT/MRI data may be solved by doing 2D segmentation slice by slice and convert them back in the end. [Here](https://github.com/xiasun/QtDicomViewer) is a simple viewer based on QT, you may find its image viewer, DICOM reader (with [GDCM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/)) and UI useful as a beginner.