# I there any way in Python to handle 3D image processing like pasting one 3d image over another 3d images completely

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3d, python-imaging-library

I've been doing transparent pasting of image object over one another using PIL.

---

```py
   from PIL import Image
   img1 = Image.open("bg")
   img2 = Image.open("fg")
   
   img1.paste(fg, (0,0), fg.convert("RGBA"))
   img1.save("final.png", "PNG")
```

this script works fine for 2d images, I just want someone to point me in the right direction. I want to create characters in 3D, so I want a solution.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do? I do not understand what you want. You can do compositing (pasting) in OpenCV, but it is not quite as simple. One needs to use a mask and do bitwise_and of the mask and its inverse with each image. Then add the results. But I do not know what you mean by doing that in 3D.

Comment: @fmw42 like one 3d model has human face and other has a hat in 3d, so I want to blend them together using any technique to get a final 3d model with both human face and glass. Hope it will help you understand what I'm saying

Comment: OpenCv isnt for 3D volumetric data. For 3D mainpulation libraries check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506641/3595907)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a 3d model of a human an another one of a hat, you can load both in the same 3D engine, adjust transformations (e.g. position, rotate and scale the hat so it looks right on the human) and render the unified scene as a single image.

Most 3D engines support this, it depends what your comfortable with.

While you could, in theory use OpenCV built from source with contributed modules such as [viz](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/viz) (which uses VTK behind the scenes and includes [samples](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/viz/samples)), or even better, the [ovis](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/ovis) package with uses [Ogre3D](https://www.ogre3d.org/),
in practice there are so many layers in between I'd go straight for the engine rather than OpenCV with an integration.

For example with Ogre3D you could find python bindings directly, there's pyglet and many other 3D libraries.

I would warmly recommend trying [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/) though.
It's got a wealth of 3D computer vision tools availble but for your scenario in particular, its 3D renderer is great and easy to use.
To load a 3D model check out the [Mesh file io tutorial](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/file_io.html#Mesh) and for rendering look at [visualisation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/visualization/visualization.html#Function-draw_geometries).
Note that Open3D ships with plenty of Python examples and even Jupyter notebooks(e.g. [file io](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/master/examples/python/geometry/file_io.ipynb), [visualisation](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/master/examples/python/visualization/visualization.ipynb)) to get started.

Comment: Can i use automation script written in python to automate merging process? @GoergeProfenze

Comment: Overall I'd say yes, however you need to pay attention to the details. With the example of placing hat on a person, if you already know the position / rotation / scale of the hat in relation to the person then the automation is trivial. Otherwise, you might need some pre-processing step where you specify how mesh A (hat) connects to mesh B (person). In theory you could try a physics based simulation, but that feels overkill. Ideally the mesh data you use would have the extra information of where mesh A needs to be placed on top of mesh B.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help and efforts. @George Profenza